# css file "used" on page, while not included

Tags: css

I have 2 pages on my website, let's say they are page1.php and page2.php

On page1.php I use jquerymobile. It's included like this on that page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile.css"/>
<script src="../js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

On page2, i do not use jquerymobile at all.

When I load page1 or page2 individually, they both work well. When I  first load page1, and then click a link to page2, the layout of page2 is messed up. When I reaload page2 (f5) everything is fine again.

It seems like jquerymobile has something to do with it. When I check a element on page2, I see this: 
[image]

Apparently the jquerymobile css is active, even though it's never included in page2 at all. When I check the source in chrome, it's also not there.

Any idea why this is happening? is it some kind of caching issue?

Comment: When you click the link to page2, is this a ajax request?

Comment: no, it's just a plain link

Comment: Can you reproduce this is a minimal example?

Comment: Check if you include other php files in the page2.php like a header or footer with the jquerymobile

Comment: no, I don't, otherwise I would also see it when I check the source, and a F5 would not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you post a live link to the page this is happening on?